# ASP.NET page is not loading CSS styles on my local iis web server

Tags: vb.net, iis

I have a local ASP.NET web site written in VB.NET runing on W7.
The default web page contains a simple style sheet which is loaded as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dchs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server"></link>
```

The page is displayed without the above styling. The style sheet does exist as I can display it via the web browers as

```
file:///c:/inetpub/wwwroot/c1/dchs.css
```

but I cannot display it via the brower using

```
http://localhost/c1/dchs.css
```

This leads me to believe that IIS has some form of access problem to the C1 directory. It a similar way I can display a jpeg image via file://c1 bit not via localhost which gives an error message

> The image "http://localhost/c1/menu.jpeg" cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.

Comment: share the errors.

Comment: Is your page also located in wwwroot\c1 ?

Comment: Yes all the scripts plus the css file and a couple of jpegs are all in the same file. All the rest of the aspx code runs fine.

Comment: @Muhammad Saqlain what do you mean by share the errors?

Comment: what error are you getting in browser console?

Comment: Currently, I am not seeing any errors in the browers console apart from The image "http://localhost/c1/menu.jpeg" cannot be displayed, because it contains errors. Do I have to anything to switch on browser errors?

Comment: Maybe try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301893/iis-7-windows-server-2008-css-file-not-loading-within-aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is the route of my problem. Having enabled Static Content in IIS, my css files loaded and "styled" my web page. Pictures still do not load. I have tried adding System.Web.StaticFileHandler as a managed handler for *.jpg files but know when I click on the missing picture, I get the HTTP 404 - resource cannot be found. This is a step in the right direction as I did not get nay error mssage before I add static content.

Answer (score 0):

How you attached the .css file to your html project? where is it located?

Options:

```
1. Drag and drop your .css file to your html page.(Inside)
```

like this:

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="images/fil.ico" />
```

Make sure all folders and files are include when project deployed And a correct calling of id or class in your css of course.

Comment: This is not a Visual Studio project. All the VB script code are in aspx files created via a text editor

Comment: Doesn't make sense, the important is you construct the code correctly according to your project path folder.